# create new coloumn from 2 fields

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I am trying to find a logic on how to create a third column based on the existing 2 fields.

How do I loop through records

I am trying with:

```
select *
case when …. then         (how to loop here?)
else end
as thirdcolumn 
from dataset
```

Comment: Even without looking at your dataset yet - you are contradicting yourself, please edit to explain more clearly. You say the third column is "nothing but a random sequence" but then "it is assigned based on the datetime info" So is it RANDOM or is it ASSIGNED BASED ON? What do you mean by "random"?  THEN:  Please keep only the tag that applies to your database (MySQL or Oracle) and delete the other one - or are you using BOTH? Thanks!

Comment: .. and no, at least if it's Oracle, you don't need a cursor, everything can be done in SQL (probably... depending on what you really need). Check out DBMS_RANDOM, specifically DBMS_RANDOM.STRING. If you need the "random" string to have a specific structure (so it is not really random), for example a random upper-case letter followed by three digits followed by two lower-case letters, you can use several calls to DBMS_RANDOM.STRING and concatenation with ||.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags (MySQL and Oracle are quite different).  Please add back the tag for the database you are actually using.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using a stored procedure.  They allow you to loop to your heart's content.  I don't understand the 20 minute part.  Maybe you should clarify that in your question.

Comment: Loop through every record in dataset and for every 20 minutes of the timestamp... need to create the 3rd column (field) that has a random number allotted for those records.

Comment: No cursor and don't loop...stop thinking loop and sql in the same sentence.  Easiest to do this if you've got a table with each 20 minute time interval already in it, but that can be created on the fly.  What logic are you using to create the third column (can't tell from your question)...and I should ask what are you trying to accomplish by doing this (it kinda seems like a pointless task)?